# Note taking on the Entourage Edge

Tags: tablet

I recently came across some free money and am considering buying a tablet.  Specifically, the entourage edge because it would be in my hands the day the money is.  What I'm curious about, however, is how well this baby can take notes.  The floor model had been on for several days and had had sever people screwing around with it and had hence crashed.

So:

- Can the entourage edge take notes in real time (ie what is the latency when dragging my pen over the ereader screen) when it has not been abused?
- how many pages of notes can it store without extending the memory?
- how well does the edge sync with a parent computer, specifically a mac?

Answer (score 2):

According to the [review on Engadget](http://www.engadget.com/2010/03/12/entourage-edge-review/), note-taking is laggy; up to a second between writing a letter and it appearing.

Answer (score 0):

That was an early review.  The note taking has been sped up considerably and although it is not quite as fast as a real pen on paper it is now a natural feel and I have not found a better writing experience on any electronic device.